# mysql replace parts of a string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this in mysql . How can I replace parts of a string in a column in MYSQL with 1000 records. Change all records form .JPG to .gif

eg. DC3444.JPG to DC3444.gif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
update your_table 
set some_column = replace(some_column, '.JPG', '.gif')
```

Comment: thanks man, worked. what about appending 0 to the start of a string of phone numbers in the records. eg. 222,334 to 0222,334

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, '.JPG','.gif')
```

Use this as reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace